# Google Scripts Not Getting Correct Page from Wordpress API

Tags: google-apps-script, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to use Google Scripts to make some calls to the Wordpress API to get back the content of a specific page (calling http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/id with UrlFetchApp)

It works fine when I just enter the request into my browser's (Chrome) address bar, it returns the page I want. However, when I use Google Scripts, sometimes it works and returns the same thing as when I use my address bar, but sometimes it seemingly just ignores what I enter for id. If I come back a while later, it starts to work again.

Any ideas what's going on?

Wordpress API documentation for pages:
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/pages/